# Таблица истинности которая считывает функцию Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Создать программное приложение автоматического построения таблиц
истинности для выражений булевой алгебры.
Программа должна позволять пользователю вводить произвольный булево
выражение, определять булевы переменные и динамично строить таблицу
истинности.

- '-' — возражения "нет"
- '+' — дизъюнкция "или"
- '*' — конъюнкция "и"
- '>' — импликация "если ..., тогда"
- '=' — эквивалентность "ровно"

програма должна принимать функцию -p+(p*q)=q, вот все что я сделал

```
def __no__(a):
    return not a


def __or__(a, b):
    return a or b


def __and__(a, b):
    return a and b


def __ifto__(a, b):
    return (not a) or b


def __equal__(a, b):
    return a == b


q = [True, False, True, False]
p = [False, True, True, False]

infunc = input('Enter your function: ')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы не парсить выражение, можно привлечь Питон вычислять введённую функцию и заполнять таблицу истинности. Для этого завести класс, который будет представлять переменные в выражении, и у него переопределить соответствующие операторы. А дальше инициализировать переменные всеми возможными значениями и получать результат введённой функции для каждого набора значений переменных при помощи штатной функции `eval()`.

```
import re

class BoolVar:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        #print("INIT =", value)

    # '-' — возражения "нет"
    def __neg__(self):
        return BoolVar(not self.value)

    # '+' — дизъюнкция "или"
    def __add__(self, other):
        return BoolVar(self.value or other.value)

    # '*' — конъюнкция "и"
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return BoolVar(self.value and other.value)

    # '>' — импликация "если ..., тогда"
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return BoolVar((not self.value) or other.value)

    # '=' — эквивалентность "ровно"
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return BoolVar(self.value == other.value)
    
    # строковое представление значения
    def __str__(self):
        return "True" if self.value else "False"

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return format(str(self), format_spec)

infunc = input('Enter your function: ')
# в питоне знак эквивалентности - это '==', так что заменяем
infunc = infunc.replace("=", "==")
# находим переменные в функции, т.е. просто буквы
# set() делает этот набор уникальным, ну и сортируем
variables = sorted(set(re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]", infunc)))
# или так, если надо без использования регулярных выражений
# variables = sorted(set([c for c in infunc if c.isalpha()]))

# просто красивое оформление для таблицы
header = [""]*2
for key in variables:
    header[0] += "-"*7 + "+"
    header[1] += f"   {key}   |"
header[0] += "-+" + "-"*7
header[1] += " | Result"
print("\n".join(header + header[0:1]))
    
vars_for_eval = {}
# вариантов входных значений для таблицы - 2 в степени кол-ва переменных
for variant in range(1 << len(variables)):
    # заполняем входной словарь c представлением переменных 
    # в виде экземпляров нашего класса для функции eval()
    # key идут в прямом порядке, а i - в обратном
    for i, key in reversed(list(enumerate(reversed(variables)))):
        # используем биты этого числа для инициализыции булевых значений 
        vars_for_eval[key] = BoolVar(variant & (1 << i))
        # вывод строки таблицы истинности
        print(f" {vars_for_eval[key]:<5}", end=" |")
    # вычисляем результат
    result = eval(infunc, {}, vars_for_eval)
    print(f" | {result:<5}")

print(header[0])
```

Оно даже чего-то считает:

```
D:\Programming\Python\1>python bools.py
Enter your function: a+b
-------+-------+-+-------
   a   |   b   | | Result
-------+-------+-+-------
 False | False | | False
 False | True  | | True
 True  | False | | True
 True  | True  | | True
-------+-------+-+-------

D:\Programming\Python\1>python bools.py
Enter your function: -x=y
-------+-------+-+-------
   x   |   y   | | Result
-------+-------+-+-------
 False | False | | False
 False | True  | | True
 True  | False | | True
 True  | True  | | False
-------+-------+-+-------

D:\Programming\Python\1>python bools.py
Enter your function: -p+(p*q)=q
-------+-------+-+-------
   p   |   q   | | Result
-------+-------+-+-------
 False | False | | False
 False | True  | | True
 True  | False | | True
 True  | True  | | True
-------+-------+-+-------
```

Кстати, программу заодно можно использовать как калькулятор. :)

```
D:\Programming\Python\1>python bools.py
Enter your function: 55*23-16**5//16
-+-------
 | Result
-+-------
 | -64271
-+-------
```

Comment: Cпасибо, вы сделали мою ночь

Comment: @HALLEPA7 Если вас ответ полностью устраивает, то не стесняйтесь пометить его как решение.

Comment: Все отметил, еще раз спасибо)

Comment: зачем eval если можно положитьфункции в словарь?

Comment: @eri А поподробнее, что вы имеете ввиду?